# How to get all the Photos from Built In Gallery into our application without using UIPickerController

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

I have been using UIPickerController to get the pics from my Built-in-Gallery into my own Application, But the issue is that the delegate related to that UIPickerCOntroller get only one pic at a time and returns me only one image. So i need to get the images one by one from PHotoGallery.

Now i want to implement my own Photo-Gallery so that i could get multiple images from Built-In photo Gallery.

Can you guys guide me how to access Builtin Gallery photo Folders and fetch all images from there into my Array so that i can make my own Photo Gallery with Multiple Selection Option

Or PLease tell me if i can manage the Multiple Selection Option from UIPickerController.

I guess Apple should provide us atleast this sort of feature that we can select multiple photos at a time from Photo gallery.

PLease guys Can u guide me with some code from any of these two Options

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use the Assets Library framework. take a look at this blog post for more details:

http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/